# Passing a Block to a function that requires a function pointer

Tags: objective-c, c, function-pointers, objective-c-blocks

I have a C function:

```
void encodeFile(void (*aFunction)(double));
```

I would like to pass an Objective-C Block to this function

```
void (^aBlock)(double) = ^(double aDouble) {...}

encodeFile(aBlock);
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You could pass in a block that _runs_ your c function.

Comment: just edited now. i hope it's more clear what i need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write your own function, and it isn't pretty:

```
static BlockFunction myBlock = ...;
static void myFunction (double value) { myBlock (value); }

...

encodeFile (&myFunction);
```

Basically, you run into lots of the problems (thread safety and so on) that blocks are designed to avoid.

Comment: the block is not static. it is passed as parameter of a method. and it could be called more than once. is that possible that it doesn't exist some __bridge that does the trick?